# Viewport height (vh) not working with position sticky

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've built a gallery layout. Each `<div class="gallery">` section fills the viewport. Here's how it looks without a sticky header. The layout works as expected using this method.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.gallery figure {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.gallery figure img {
  display: block;
  /* Make images responsive */
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Fill .gallery width and height */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>Header</span>
</header>

<div class="gallery">
  <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>

<footer>
  <span>Footer</span>
</footer>
```

Next, I've added a sticky header, like so.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
}

.gallery figure {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.gallery figure img {
  display: block;
  /* Make images responsive */
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Fill .gallery width and height */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>Header</span>
</header>

<div class="gallery">
  
  <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
    
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  
  <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
    
</div>

<footer>
  <span>Footer</span>
</footer>
```

To account for the sticky header, I've added `height: calc(100vh - 120px);` to `.gallery`. This works for the first `.gallery` parent, but something funky is happening with the last parent `.gallery`. As you can see, the footer overlaps.

**EDIT**

If you inspect `<figure>` on the sticky header example, you'll notice that it's correctly calculating the height. For example, at a resolution of 1366x768, the height of `<figure>` measures 648px in height (768px - 120px). However, the `<a>` and `<img>` elements show a height of 768px.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you reduced the gallery to less than 100vh but you kept the image at 100vh so you will logically have the overflow. Reduce the image too or rely on height:100%

Comment: Yep! looks like we posted at the same time. I've just posted an answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my edit, the problem lies with the the `<a>` and `<img>` elements not being contained with the `<figure>` element. I've resolved this by adding `height: 100%;` to `.gallery figure a` and `.gallery figure img`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.gallery figure {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.gallery figure a,
.gallery figure img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%; /* Fills the height of <figure> */
}

.gallery figure img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>Header</span>
</header>

<div class="gallery">
  
  <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
    
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  
  <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
  
    <figure>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg/1200px-Yawning_cat_portrait_%288423278464%29.jpg" alt="Cat">
    </a>
  </figure>
    
</div>

<footer>
  <span>Footer</span>
</footer>
```